# c# http post request with basic authentication

Tags: c#

I've written a python function to move a router's IO port via a HTTP post request with Basic Authentivation. This works fine. But now I'd like to implement the sam with C#.

Here is my python function:

```
def io_on(ip='192.168.2.1', username='adm', password='123456'):
if not isinstance(ip, str):
    print('not string')
try:
    payload ='_ajax=1&_web_cmd=%21%0Aio%20output%201%20on%0A'
    r = requests.post('http://{}/apply.cgi'.format(ip), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), data=payload, timeout=3)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('{} : IO ON'.format(ip))
    elif r.status_code == 401:
        print('{} : Auth error'.format(ip))
    else:
        print(r.status_code)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I've experimented with NetWorkCredentials with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
    try
    {
        string username = "adm", password = "123456";
        string payload = "http://192.168.2.1/apply.cgi/?_ajax=1&_web_cmd=%21%0Aio%20output%201%20on%0A";


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(payload);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }

        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Auth error");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a GET not a POST as per your paste

Comment: Could you please adjust it?

Comment: Just change this line  request.Method = "POST"; to  request.Method = "GET";

Comment: I did it, thanks. I still got an unauthorized packet. Here is how I do it now: https://pastebin.com/JFt6bjMY

Comment: You are still using POST

Comment: I need to use a POST, to move the router's IO :-) With the python script, it works perfectly

Comment: I folloewd the MSDN, but still got unauthorized packets. Here is the latest code: https://pastebin.com/MdmaWWD8

Answer (score 1):

Here's my way to make POST with basic authentication.

```
var authValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{login}:{password}")));

using (var client = new HttpClient() { DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = authValue } })
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://localhost:44396/Documentation/All?pageNumber=0&pageSize=10", httpContent).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```